# Weird Syntax Error in MySQL function in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am getting a really weird error in the following piece of code:

```
mysqli_query($database,"INSERT INTO userdetails (username,email_id)VALUES ($_POST['username'],$_POST['email_id'])";
```

Error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in E:\Xampp\htdocs\newsreg.php on line 19

Line 19 is the code I have mentioned above. I have been trying to crack this but to no use. It works if the `'` is removed from `[]` . According to me, $_POST['username'] and $_POST[username] both are valid.

`username` is the name attribute of a text box in HTML form.

What is wrong with the above code?

Comment: If you were using bind variables with your queries, then this wouldn't even be an issue

Comment: [Your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap your values in simple quote since its varchar.

```
mysqli_query($database,"INSERT INTO userdetails (username,email_id)VALUES ('{$_POST['username']}','{$_POST['email_id']}')";
```

Answer (score 0):

update your query to be, you must put your string value between 2 quota `'` also concat your $_POST val by this way:

```
mysqli_query($database,"INSERT INTO userdetails (username,email_id)
VALUES ('".$_POST['username']."','".$_POST['email_id']."')";
```

Answer (score 0):

1) It's not parsing the $_POST variables properly, so it's getting confused
2) You're not putting quotes around your variables

```
mysqli_query($database,"INSERT INTO userdetails (username,email_id)VALUES ('{$_POST['username']}','{$_POST['email_id']}')";
```

You really ought to use parameterization here, which will encapsulate it for you.

Comment: It gives the same error with `('$_POST['username']','$_POST['email_id']')`

Comment: You're missing the brackets around the variables

Comment: What difference is the brackets making?
Can you explain a bit?
And even `mysqli_query($database,"INSERT INTO user (username)"."VALUES('$_POST[username]')");` this works.

Comment: The brackets tells PHP interpreter that the whole $_POST['username'] within the string is a variable, not just $_POST.

Comment: why is `mysqli_query($database,"INSERT INTO user (username)"."VALUES('$_POST[username]')");` working without brackets?

Comment: Got me. I'd really recommend using bind parameters, however, since doing it this way is a huge security risk.